# Implicit conversion in the other direction

Tags: c++

A wrapper class is nice when you can't modify the wrapped class. With the wrapper I can add certain functionality and convenience, and I can still make the wrapper accepted in functions that use the wrapped type by using an implicit conversion from the wrapper to the wrapped type. Something like this:

```
struct vec {
    __m128 m128;
    inline operator __m128 &() {
        return m128;
    }
    //convenience to add functionality related to the wrapped variable inserted here
}
```

And this works well.

Now my question is, can you implicitly convert the other way around, from __m128 to vec, when you have no access to the wrapped type source or can't modify it?

Comment: Try a single-argument constructor : `vec::vec(const __m128&)`. Bear in mind that implicit conversions are evil, and bidirectional ones are *pure* evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a constructor that <sup>(1)</sup>accepts a single `__m128` argument. If you don't add `explicit` then it provides an implicit conversion. This is called a **converting constructor**.

C++03 12.3.1/1

> **”** A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` that can be called with a single parameter specifies a conversion from the type of its first parameter to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.

C++11 (quite unreasonably, IMHO) extended the meaning of the term to cover “conversion” from multiple specified arguments, to the type of the constructor's class:

C++11 12.3.1/1

> **”** A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` specifies a conversion from the types of its
>   parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> If it has more arguments then these must be defaulted or be a `...` ellipsis.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just write a constructor taking a single `__m128` which is not marked `explicit`:

```
vec (__m128 m128) //maybe take by const-ref (I don't know what __m128 is)
  : m128(m128)
{}
```